# Removing duplicate row from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, max, rowid

```
sql> delete from emp where rowid not in (select max(rowid) from emp group by empno);
```

Can any one explain what max(rowid) do ?? Please explain this sql program

Comment: you might want to do a "group by" with all the columns and "count(1)" and adding the "having count(1)>1" on it so you detect the duplicates. After that you could place a statement to delete the retuned even or odd rownums from it.

Answer (score 1):

`rowid` is a pseudo-column available for all rows in Oracle tables.  It is really the address of the row, identifying the data page and offset on the data page.

As with (just about) any other data type, you can take the maximum value.  So, what this is doing is calculating the maximum of `rowid` for each `empno`.  The `delete` is then deleting all rows that are *not* one of the maxima.

This has the effect of keeping a single row for each `empno`.

`rowid` itself is quite well [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm).